# Return object with a certain property

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I got an object named `app` and this contains an NSMutableArray named `windows` and in this array there are all objects of the type `window`.  The window object got a property type named `ident` so I can access them like this:

```
for (Window *window in _app.windows){
    NSLog(@"%@", window.ident);
}
```

I'm searching for an alternative way for this code:

```
[_app.windows objectAtIndex:index];
```

Instead I need something like:

**Pseudo code:**

```
[_app.windows objectWithIdent:ident];
```

How can I achive this?

Comment: Create a Dictionary of `window` instead of array. Then you can use `[_app.windows objectForKey:ident];`

Comment: In your for loop replace the NSLog with an if ([ident isEqual:window.ident])

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya I still need to be able to have all the array functionallity since I've used this as an array in my whole program

Comment: [dict allValues] gives you array

Comment: How can I make the NSDictonairy in my for-loop that I said in my question with al lthe windows?

Comment: i got confused... is this ios or osx? UIWindows???

Comment: Its not UIWindow, its a self made type, can I use KeyValueCoding for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is create a quick helper:

```
- (Window *)windowWithIdent:(NSString *)ident
{
    for (Window *window in _app.windows) {
        if ([window.ident isEqualToString:ident]) {
            return window;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

For a more general solution, you can create a category method on `NSArray`:

```
@implementation NSArray (MyAdditions)
    - (id)firstObjectMatchingBlockPredicate:(BOOL (^)(id object))block
    {
        for (id o in self) {
            if (block(o)) {
                return o;
            }
        }

        return nil;
    }
@end
```

And then

```
[_app.windows firstObjectMatchingBlockPredicate:^BOOL(Window *w) {
    return [w.ident isEqualToString:@"ident"];
}];
```

Comment: Just remember this is O(n) lookup time so if you have a large number of windows in your array, you may want to use some other more efficient way to do this.

Comment: and what is a large number?

Comment: Well, you should start with Instruments to actually see if you have a bottle neck. But even if you have a couple of hundred objects, the code here should still be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Use KVC:

```
[_app.windows valueForKeyPath:@"[collect].{ident == %@", @"5"];
```

I may be wrong with the predicate format, but you can read about this method.

The other option, is to build a dictionary.

Comment: What does this "ident == 5" ?

Comment: Edited. It's actually the query. the 5 is just an example.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Window 0x848cca0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key [collect].'

Answer (score 0):

Using NSPredicate:

```
NSArray *result = [app.windows filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ident == %@", @"someIdentifier"]];
if (result.count > 0)
{
//Success
}
else
{
//No result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a NSMutableDictionary of windows instead of NSMutableArray of windows.

Then, you can fill your Dictionary with windows and set your `ident` as the key.

With this, you can get your window like this:

```
[_app.windows objectForKey:ident];
```

You can fill the dictionary with windows like this:

```
[_app.windows setObject:someWindow forKey:someUniqueIdent];
```